Setting Whiptail yesno default to no
Is there a way to have the whiptail yesno choice box set to default no ?
if (whiptail --title "STEAM GAME SERVER 1" --yesno "ARE YOU SURE TO REBOOT LINUX OS?" 10 60) then
"Yes" is the default highlighted choice, I would like to have "no" set as deafult in case when someone it to quickly in hitting the keyboard button

Always check the help or man pages, sometimes the feature you are looking for is right there:
$ whiptail --help
Box options: 
    --msgbox <text> <height> <width>
    --yesno  <text> <height> <width>
    ...
Options: (depend on box-option)
    ...
    --defaultno         default no button
    ...

So in your case it would be:
whiptail --title "STEAM GAME SERVER 1" --yesno --defaultno "ARE YOU SURE TO REBOOT LINUX OS?" 10 60

